# Use ffmpeg to create a new hls with no recoding

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to read a hls playlist with `ffmpeg` and create a new playlist with no re-encoding:

```
ffmpeg 
     -i 'playlist.m3u8' 
     -c copy
     -map 0:0
     -map 1:1
     -map 2:2
     -map 3:3
     -map 4:4
     -f hls
     -hls_time 5
     -hls_playlist_type vod
     -hls_segment_type mpegts
     -hls_segment_filename encoded/%v/%03d.ts
     -master_pl_name playlist.m3u8
     -var_stream_map 'v:0 v:1 v:2 v:3 v:4' encoded/%v/chunk.m3u8
```

But this ends with:

> `[hls @ 0x7f7b9d98fb40] Unable to map stream at v:1`

(full log is here: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/fe384863640d6fc94d6f2424da9f3d22)

1. Is there a way to avoid the `-map x:x` and say something like: "just copy all streams"
2. Is there a way to avoid the `-var_stream_map x:y` and also just say "copy all streams"